# Changing statue based on other factors using R

Tags: r, database, variables, var

So I have a key factor `lk` that generate random number between 1 and 9. Based on that factor some change must occur in my data as follows;

My data looks like this:

| statue | cost | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t | 43 | 21 |
| n | 5 | 17 |
| n | 27 | 21 |
| n | 26 | 35 |
| t | 39 | 38 |
| n | 12 | 22 |
| t | 42 | 13 |
| t | 38 | 32 |
| n | 39 | 15 |
| t | 25 | 38 |

If `lk > sum (df$statue=="t")` say `lk == 7`   and `sum (df$statue=="t") == 5` so two individuals with `statue=="n"`   and the smallest  `cost`  must change their status from  `n`  to  `t`  in this example individual 2 and 6.

And if `lk <= sum (df$statue=="t")` say `lk == 3` and `sum (df$statue=="t") == 5` so two individuals with `statue=="t"`   and the biggest  `salary`  must change their status from  `t`  to  `n`  in this example individual 5 and 10.

I hope I made it clear;

Any ideas please;

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you wanted...

```
check_lk <- function(lk, data){
  sum_t <- nrow(data[data$statue == "t",])
  if(lk > sum_t){
    # create reordered data, by statue and cost (ascending order)
    tmp <- data[order(data$statue, data$cost),]
    # first two records represent statue n and two lowest cost
    # add another conditional check if needed
    tmp[1:2, "statue"] <- "t"
    tmp <- tmp[ order(as.numeric(row.names(tmp))), ]
  } else{ 
    # create reordered data, by statue and salary (ascending order)
    tmp <- data[order(data$statue, data$salary),]
    tmp[c(nrow(tmp), nrow(tmp)-1), "statue"] <- "n"
    tmp <- tmp[ order(as.numeric(row.names(tmp))), ]
  }
  return(tmp)
}
```

Loading data given:

```
df <- structure(list(statue = c("t", "n", "n", "n", "t", "n", "t", 
"t", "n", "t"), cost = c(43L, 5L, 27L, 26L, 39L, 12L, 42L, 38L, 
39L, 25L), salary = c(21L, 17L, 21L, 35L, 38L, 22L, 13L, 32L, 
15L, 38L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Test for lk = 7

```
check_lk(7, df)

   statue cost salary
1       t   43     21
2       t    5     17
3       n   27     21
4       n   26     35
5       t   39     38
6       t   12     22
7       t   42     13
8       t   38     32
9       n   39     15
10      t   25     38
```

Test for lk=3

```
check_lk(3, df)
   statue cost salary
1       t   43     21
2       n    5     17
3       n   27     21
4       n   26     35
5       n   39     38
6       n   12     22
7       t   42     13
8       t   38     32
9       n   39     15
10      n   25     38
```